# Spread theme in sx prop MUI 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

The previous code, which used v4, was

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  toolbarMargin: {
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar
  }
}))
```

How to migrate this code to MUI v5 using `sx` prop, I tried using it like this

```js
<Box
  sx={{
    ...(theme) => theme.mixins.toolbar,
  }}
/>
```

but the `theme` was not defined.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:

```
<Box sx={theme => theme.mixins.toolbar} />
```

or

```
<Box sx={theme => ({
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  // other sx stuff
})} />
```

As you can also pass a function with `theme` as parameter to the `sx` prop, it must return valid sx object.

Comment: It does not generate any errors in the IDE, but there is no toolbar styling in the CSS, which may indicate that the code did not pass to the `sx`

Comment: are you sure `theme.mixins.toolbar` is set? Please provide a codesandbox to allow me to reproduce the issue

Comment: i've just tested those two solutions on my side and it works fine for both code (using default MUI theme)

Comment: You can debug the `theme` passed to `sx` prop by setting it to: `sx={theme => {console.log(theme); return {};}}`

Comment: i'm able to get the result if i define every each style like in `sx` `minHeight: (theme) => theme.mixins.toolbar.minHeight`, if i use your solution, i just got css class named `css-0`

Comment: Also got this warning in console when using Box `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'sx' of type 'function' supplied to 'ForwardRef(Box)', expected 'object'.`

Answer (score 2):

For me most of the solutions above resulted in an non fatal error, as sx accepts object, not functions. This worked:

```
<Box
sx={{
    "&": (theme) => theme["whateverYouWishToSpread"]
}}
>{someStuff}</Box>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `styled()` is probably less convoluted.

```js
const Container = styled('div')(theme => theme.mixins.toolbar)
```